# How to generate a list of random NxN matrics with all diagonal elements are zero？

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to generate a list of random NxN matrics with all diagonal elements zero. I use the command

```
RM[n_, p_] := Table[RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0}], {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]
N0 = Table[RM[50, 0.1], 100];
```

to generate the matrics and then write

```
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++, N2 = N0[[i]] - Diagonal[N0[[i]]] // MatrixForm]
```

to make all parts in N0 have zeros on their diagonal. However, it doesn't work since Mathematica said the parts in N2 (except part1) do not exist.

Comment: It depends very much from which distribution you're pulling the matrices.

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/26598)

Comment: Hi there, the probability density is uniform. But I am still confused about how to generate it. I can find a single matrix with all zeros on the diagonal but cannot do it with a list, say a sample that contains 100 matrics.

Comment: How about `N0 = Table[# - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@# &@RM[50, 0.1], 100];`? This will subtract off the diagonal elements on the fly.

Comment: reply to March. Thanks for help. I tried the command and use diagonal[] to verify if it worked, but several numbers are remaining on the diagonal.

Comment: Just zero them after the fact. `In[45]:= 
RM[n_, p_] := 
 Table[RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0.}], {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}]
nn = 3;
N0 = Table[RM[nn, 0.8], 10];
Do[N0[[All, j, j]] = 0., {j, nn}];
N0[[1 ;; 2]]

Out[49]= {{{0., 0.863311, 0.768276}, {0.579728, 0., 0.}, {0.128724, 
   0.711393, 0.}}, {{0., -0.0571237, 0.658995}, {0., 
   0., -0.896609}, {0.437745, -0.626474, 0.}}}` Note I use 0. to allow these to be packed arrays (improves size/speed in further usage).

Answer (score 3):

Using [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dim = 4;
nmat = 5;

SeedRandom[1234];
```

**EDIT:**

```
RM[n_Integer?(# > 1&), p_?(0 <= # <= 1 &)] :=
 SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j != i :>
    RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0}]},
  {n, n}]

MatrixForm /@ (N0 = Table[RM[dim, 0.7], nmat])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! But there is another restriction that matrix-elements are 0 with probability 1-p, and with probability p are randomly drawn real numbers between 1 and -1. So only using RandomReal might not be enough?

Comment: Corrected randomizer

Answer (score 2):

If dim is the dimension and nmat the number of matrices in the list:

```
dim = 2;
nmat = 3
res = Table[t = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dim, dim}]; t - Diagonal[t], {nmat}] ;
MatrixForm /@ res
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to generate an n x n matrix with uniform random elements and a zero diagonal:

```
neb[z_] := ReplacePart[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[1], {z, z}], {i_, i_} :> 0]

MatrixForm[neb[5]]
```

0              {0.927086}     {0.632727}     {0.794216}     {0.111677}

{0.187628}     0              {0.859068}     {0.496428}     {0.901312}

{0.372348}     {0.586887}     0              {0.686587}     {0.83178}

{0.636274}     {0.286791}     {0.406237}     0              {0.167102}

{0.00708581}   {0.89337}      {0.126658}     {0.108218}     0

Comment: Unfortunately, you have a slight error.  `UniformDistribution[1]` doesn't do what you guessed it does .  `UniformDistribution[]` does what you need.  (`UniformDistribution[1]` generates a 1D list, rather than a single value).